# Oracle DB | Issue with agent and OMS connection

Tags: oracle, oracle-enterprise-manager

We performed a "P2V" migration to a local VMware host last night to get an old physical Oracle server over to a new virtual home (we covered all the licensing aspects, we're OK there).  Prior to starting the virtualization process we brought all services and instances offline.  Coming up on the virtual side went very smooth, with everything being operational expect an error we're seeing in Enterprise Manager.  The error we're seeing is:

> Agent is unable to communicate with the OMS. (REASON = Agent is
>   Unreachable (REASON : Agent to OMS Communication is broken OMS
>   platform services are not available)

We've done the normal troubleshooting, and running EMCTL STATUS AGENT returns:

> emctl status agent 
>   Oracle Enterprise Manager Cloud Control 13c Release 1 Copyright (c) 1996, 2015 Oracle Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>   --------------------------------------------------------------- Agent Version          : 13.1.0.0.0 OMS Version            : 13.1.0.0.0
>   Protocol Version       : 12.1.0.1.0 Agent Home             :
>   /oracle/product/agent/agent_inst Agent Log Directory    :
>   /oracle/product/agent/agent_inst/sysman/log Agent Binaries         :
>   /oracle/product/agent/agent_13.1.0.0.0 Core JAR Location      :
>   /oracle/product/agent/agent_13.1.0.0.0/jlib Agent Process ID       :
>   32622 Parent Process ID      : 32476 Agent URL              :
>   https://xxxx:3872/emd/main/ Local Agent URL in NAT :
>   https://xxxx:3872/emd/main/ Repository URL         :
>   https://xxxx:4903/empbs/upload Started at             : 2020-01-25
>   09:52:01 Started by user        : oracle Operating System       :
>   Linux version 3.0.101-0.46-default (amd64) Number of Targets      : 75
>   Last Reload            : 2020-01-25 10:29:21 Last successful upload
>   : 2020-01-25 10:59:32 Last attempted upload                        :
>   2020-01-25 10:59:32 Total Megabytes of XML files uploaded so far :
>   10.25 Number of XML files pending upload           : 0 Size of XML files pending upload(MB)         : 0 Available disk space on upload
>   filesystem    : 46.30% Collection Status                            :
>   Collections enabled Heartbeat Status                             : Ok
>   Last attempted heartbeat to OMS              : 2020-01-25 10:59:25
>   Last successful heartbeat to OMS             : 2020-01-25 10:59:25
>   Next scheduled heartbeat to OMS              : 2020-01-25 11:00:25

We're at a loss here.  Any advice on how to fix this?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As they say, time heals all wounds.  After investigating for around two hours, the issue cleared on its own.